# Creating an option for writing a post without an author attribution for a group blog on Wordpress

Tags: theme-development

I'm developing a group blog on wordpress (first time working with it) and the client has requested that a 'None' option be added where an item can be posted without a "by" attribution. So basically there would be one article / excerpt template for attributed author's posts and another for the none option where the byline would just be the date posted without the "by [author name]."  Is this possible with wordpress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do, but would take hacking up the theme. One convention I've seen is to create a user with a generic name, like Guest, or the name of your site.

If you would still like to hack away. Then put a condition around the line\s in the template that displays the author like so:

```
<?php if (get_the_author() != 'none') : ?> 
    <?php the_author(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or alternately, the shorthand...

```
<?php echo (get_the_author() != 'none') ? get_the_author() : ''; ?>
```

Then you define an author named 'none'.

The post will only display the author's name if the name isn't 'none'.